# DatePicker in XPages: disable onblur event when handwritten

Tags: datepicker, xpages

Is it possible to disable the opening of the datepicker when i write a date by hand in a datepicker field?

It's very noisy because in this scenario, when i leave the field after typing the date, the datepicker is opened again, and to close i need to click again on the field and then to click out

Thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

You could try some JS magic. Hook an event on the keydown in the entry field. When an entry is made unlink the event that triggers the date picker, if the field is empty relink it. With some Firebug sessions you should be able to figure out the fine-print

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use other JS frameworks for date / time entries lately (mostly jQuery which has a good bunch of intuitive controls in this field). So I set the Xpage control to ***not*** use the picker dialog and use "my own" instead.